# yes/no field not working after applying PnPProvisioningTemplate

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, sitepages, pnp-provisioning

I'm applying a PnPTemplate file to a communication site in SharePoint Online. This template contains a yes/no column that is added to the ***Site Pages*** library. The field shows up in the default view, but doesn't seem to work in any way. The PnP template applies normally and there is no error.

---

```
            <Field Type="Boolean" DisplayName="publiser til alle" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" ID="{a0985703-d5c1-4ac6-8c53-92ae6867a68f}" SourceID="{{listid:Site Pages}}" StaticName="publisertilalle" Name="publisertilalle" ColName="bit1" RowOrdinal="0" CustomFormatter="" Required="FALSE" Version="1">
            <Default>0</Default>
            </Field>
```

---

I made the field/column on one site and then used *get-PnPProvisioningTemplate* to get the correct field tag format.
When I add a new page there is no default properties, and I can't see them if I edit the page. If I view the library settings I can see the column and it seems to be correct.

Is it not supported? Please see my photos underneath.

***Appreciate any thoughts and answers!***

---

[image: Site Pages - default view]

---

[image: Library settings - seems normal]

---

[image: Page details - shows nothing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the custom fields to a group and content type, and added them to the Site Pages columns in library settings. Then I used the get-pnpprovisioningtemplate and applied it once again - and the fields/columns work.